# Xbox 360 Elite hard drive too small

Tags: xbox-360, destiny

I need 8GB of space on the hard drive for Destiny, but I have only got 4GB of space and can't afford to delete any of it.  Also, because I have an internal hard drive, I can't get a different one and interchange them.

Is there some way I can get Destiny to run without purchasing a new 360?

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: is there a way to get destiny to run without getting anew Xbox360?

Comment: Buy a hard drive for your model of 360.

Comment: you cant because its an internal hard drive, i did try looking for one though

Comment: is there really nothing i can do but to sell destiny?

Comment: It's actually quite simple process to swap even the internal hard drive on the xbox 360 elites....http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/system/add-remove-hard-drive

Comment: @Thomas the 4GB model has the capability of upgrading the HDD. You need to find your model of 360, and find the appropriate hard-drive for it. Install instructions can be found online, but depend on your type of 360.

Comment: Do you only have a 4GB hard drive or you only have that much space left?  You could uninstall games you don't play anymore, I think you can still preserve the save files if you decide to reinstall them at another time.

Answer (score -2):

You can get a new hard drive for Xbox 360 elite. This shows you how to get to the hard drive
http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/system/add-remove-hard-drive

Comment: In order for this to be a proper answer, you need to summarize the information at the link.  That way, if the page ever goes down, your answer is still valid.